# Common Lisp: Why does this create circular list: (setf (car ) (append ))?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I am trying to understand why this produces what seems to be circular list.

```
 * (progn
 (setf (car *x*) (append '(3) *x*))
 2)

2  ;; No "apparent issue setting the value. Hence it is related to printing `*x*`
*x* ;; infinite loop, perhaps due to the structure of *x*??
```

Why is it a circular list? I would expect that it should not be a circular list

What is different between this question and the "duplicate" question:

In this question, I believe `*x*` should not be a circular list. In the duplicate answer chain, it is shown how to create a circular list, and neither of the example uses the result of `append` in the `setf`.

Alright, I found the answer:
My confusion arises from misunderstanding the [spec](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm) where they say that append returns a new list.

Evidently a new list does not mean that each and every member of it is new (does not mean a copy is returned). The last argument of append is actually shared...

Comment: in the marked as duplicate response, the `setf` function does not set the variable to a result from `append`

Comment: Why shouldn't it be a circular list? Take a piece of paper and draw the graph of cons cells.

Comment: Set `*print-circle*` to T and you will see the cycle

Comment: @coredump my question is, why does this create a cycle, not how to print it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the reader, but the printer that is in an infinite loop.
Most implementations have a variable to limit the top level printer,
see [`*PRINT-LEVEL*`, `*PRINT-LENGTH*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_lev.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will edit the question